# Traversing a list of lists by index within a loop, to reformat strings

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of lists that looks like this, that was pulled in from a poorly formatted csv file:

```
DF = [['Customer Number: 001 '],
 ['Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with'],
 ['Customer Number: 666 '],
 ['Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that hidden decaf skit from SNL'],
 ['Customer Number: 103 '],
 ['Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain'],
 ['Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins hairdresser'],
 ['Notes: name address birthday social security number on file'],
 ['Customer Number: 007 '],
 ['Notes: looked a lot like James Bond'],
 ['Notes: came in with a martini']]
```

I would like to end up with a new structure like this:

```
['Customer Number: 001 Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with',
 'Customer Number: 666 Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that hidden decaf skit from SNL',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins hairdresser',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: name address birthday social security number on file',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: looked a lot like James Bond',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: came in with a martini']
```

after which I can further split, strip, etc.

So, I used the facts that:

- the customer number always starts with `Customer Number`
- the `Notes` are always longer
- the number of `Notes` never exceeds 5

to code up what is clearly an absurd solution, even though it works.

```
DF = [item for sublist in DF for item in sublist]
DF = DF + ['stophere']
DF2 = []

for record in DF:
    if (record[0:17]=="Customer Number: ") & (record !="stophere"):
        DF2.append(record + DF[DF.index(record)+1])
        if len(DF[DF.index(record)+2]) >21:
            DF2.append(record + DF[DF.index(record)+2])
            if len(DF[DF.index(record)+3]) >21:
                DF2.append(record + DF[DF.index(record)+3])
                if len(DF[DF.index(record)+4]) >21:
                    DF2.append(record + DF[DF.index(record)+4])
                    if len(DF[DF.index(record)+5]) >21:
                        DF2.append(record + DF[DF.index(record)+5])
```

Would anyone mind recommending a more stable and intelligent solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 13):

Just keep track of when we find a new customer:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

out = []
for sub in DF:
    if sub[0].startswith("Customer Number"):
        cust = sub[0]
    else:
        out.append(cust + sub[0])
pp(out)
```

Output:

```
['Customer Number: 001 Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with',
 'Customer Number: 666 Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that '
 'hidden decaf skit from SNL',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins '
 'hairdresser',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: name address birthday social security number '
 'on file',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: looked a lot like James Bond',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: came in with a martini']
```

If the customer can repeat again later and you want them grouped together use a dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for sub in DF:
    if sub[0].startswith("Customer Number"):
        cust = sub[0]
    else:
        d[cust].append(cust + sub[0])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
pp(d)

{'Customer Number: 001 ': ['Customer Number: 001 Notes: Bought a ton of '
                           'stuff and was easy to deal with'],
 'Customer Number: 007 ': ['Customer Number: 007 Notes: looked a lot like '
                           'James Bond',
                           'Customer Number: 007 Notes: came in with a '
                           'martini'],
 'Customer Number: 103 ': ['Customer Number: 103 Notes: bought a ton of '
                           'stuff got a free keychain',
                           'Customer Number: 103 Notes: gave us a referral '
                           'to his uncles cousins hairdresser',
                           'Customer Number: 103 Notes: name address '
                           'birthday social security number on file'],
 'Customer Number: 666 ': ['Customer Number: 666 Notes: acted and looked '
                           'like Chris Farley on that hidden decaf skit '
                           'from SNL']}
```

Based on your comment and error you seem to have lines coming before an actual customer so we can add them to the first customer in the list:

```
# added ["foo"] before we see any customer

DF = [["foo"],['Customer Number: 001 '],
 ['Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with'],
 ['Customer Number: 666 '],
 ['Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that hidden decaf skit from SNL'],
 ['Customer Number: 103 '],
 ['Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain'],
 ['Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins hairdresser'],
 ['Notes: name address birthday social security number on file'],
 ['Customer Number: 007 '],
 ['Notes: looked a lot like James Bond'],
 ['Notes: came in with a martini']]


from pprint import pprint as pp

from itertools import takewhile, islice

# find lines up to first customer
start = list(takewhile(lambda x: "Customer Number:" not in x[0], DF))

out = []
ln = len(start)
# if we had data before we actually found a customer this will be True
if start: 
    # so set cust to first customer in list and start adding to out
    cust = DF[ln][0]
    for sub in start:
        out.append(cust + sub[0])
# ln will either be 0 if start is empty else we start at first customer
for sub in islice(DF, ln, None):
    if sub[0].startswith("Customer Number"):
        cust = sub[0]
    else:
        out.append(cust + sub[0])
```

Which outputs:

```
 ['Customer Number: 001 foo',
 'Customer Number: 001 Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with',
 'Customer Number: 666 Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that '
 'hidden decaf skit from SNL',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins '
 'hairdresser',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: name address birthday social security number '
 'on file',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: looked a lot like James Bond',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: came in with a martini']
```

I presumed you would consider lines that come before any customer to actually belong to that first customer.

Comment: @MattO'Brien, then your list does not actually have as the first element `Customer Number:...` so that would mean a different approach is needed. What should happen if a customer comes after text as in we have not seen a customer yet? i.e `[["foo"],["Customer Number: 100"]]` is the start fof your list

Comment: ah...I'm sorry. I made a small error. I'm going to delete my comment. Thanks!

Comment: @MattO'Brien,  no worries, I will leave the alternative code up anyway as it may be useful to someone.

Answer (score 4):

Your basic objective is to group the notes and associate it with the customer. And since the list is already sorted, you can simply use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like this

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

def build_notes(it):
    customer, func = "", lambda x: x.startswith('Customer')
    for item, grp in groupby(chain.from_iterable(DF), key=func):
        if item:
            customer = next(grp)
        else:
            for note in grp:
                yield customer + note
            # In Python 3.x, you can simply do
            # yield from (customer + note for note in grp)
```

Here, we flatten the actual list of lists to a sequence of strings, with [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). And then we group the lines which have `Customer` in it and the lines which don't. If the line has `Customer`, then `item` will be `True` otherwise `False`. If `item` is `True`, then we get the customer information and when the `item` is `False`, we iterate over the grouped notes and return one string at a time by concatenating the customer information with the notes.

So, when you run the code,

```
print(list(build_notes(DF)))
```

you get

```
['Customer Number: 001 Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with',
 'Customer Number: 666 Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that hidden decaf skit from SNL',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins hairdresser',
 'Customer Number: 103 Notes: name address birthday social security number on file',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: looked a lot like James Bond',
 'Customer Number: 007 Notes: came in with a martini']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DF = [['Customer Number: 001 '],
 ['Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with'],
 ['Customer Number: 666 '],
 ['Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that hidden decaf skit from SNL'],
 ['Customer Number: 103 '],
 ['Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain'],
 ['Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins hairdresser'],
 ['Notes: name address birthday social security number on file'],
 ['Customer Number: 007 '],
 ['Notes: looked a lot like James Bond'],
 ['Notes: came in with a martini']]

custnumstr = None
out = []
for df in DF:
     if df[0].startswith('Customer Number'):
         custnumstr = df[0]
     else:
         out.append(custnumstr + df[0])

for e in out:
    print e
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use OrderedDict, where keys are customers and values is a list of notes:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

DF_dict = OrderedDict()

for subl in DF:
    if 'Customer Number' in subl[0]:  
        DF_dict[subl[0]] = []
        continue    
    last_key = list(DF_dict.keys())[-1]
    DF_dict[last_key].append(subl[0])


for customer, notes in  DF_dict.items():
    for a_note in notes:
        print(customer,a_note)
```

Results in:

```
Customer Number: 001  Notes: Bought a ton of stuff and was easy to deal with
Customer Number: 666  Notes: acted and looked like Chris Farley on that hidden decaf skit from SNL
Customer Number: 103  Notes: bought a ton of stuff got a free keychain
Customer Number: 103  Notes: gave us a referral to his uncles cousins hairdresser
Customer Number: 103  Notes: name address birthday social security number on file
Customer Number: 007  Notes: looked a lot like James Bond
Customer Number: 007  Notes: came in with a martini
```

Putting values in a dict like this, can be useful if you want to calculate how many notes are for a given customer, count the notes, or just select notes for a given customer.

Alternative, without getting calling `list(DF_dict.keys())[-1]` in each iteration :

```
last_key = ''

for subl in DF:
    if 'Customer Number' in subl[0]:  
        DF_dict[subl[0]] = []
        last_key = subl[0]
        continue    

    DF_dict[last_key].append(subl[0])
```

And new shorter version, using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

DF_dict = defaultdict(list)

for subl in DF:
    if 'Customer Number' in subl[0]:         
        customer = subl[0]
        continue        

    DF_dict[customer].append(subl[0])
```

Comment: You could also `k = subl[0] DF_dict.setdefault(k,[])` and forget the continue

Answer (score 2):

As long as the format is the same as your example, this should work.

```
final_list = []
for outer_list in DF:
    for s in outer_list:
        if s.startswith("Customer"):
            cust = s
        elif s.startswith("Notes"):
            final_list.append(cust + s)

for f in final_list:
    print f
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can count on the first element being a customer, you can do it like this.

Simply loop through each item. If the item is a customer, set the current customer as that string. Else, it is a note, so you append the customer and the note to the list of results.

```
customer = ""
results = []
for record in DF:
    data = record[0]
    if "Customer" in data:
        customer = data
    elif "Notes" in data:
        result = customer + data
        results.append(result)

print(results)
```